# How to execute 2 async calls in redux-observable epic and return/dispatch action on result of each one

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have an action which requires me to go to the server, get 2 chunks of data, and on getting those then dispatching an action with each chunk of data respectively.
This is to be done when action$.ofType(PROCESSDATA).
Pretty new to rxjs and I can't quite figure out the right combination.

```
epic = (action$) => {
    return action$.ofType(PROCESSDATA)
        //should I be using switchMap? It is for initialising data 
        //so I figure no point in carrying on with original request 
        //if a new one comes in
        .switchMap(action=>{
            //is merge right? return statement currently just gives me
            //an error about my epic does not return a stream
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            return Observable.merge(
               Observable.ajax({
                 url:'/first',
                 headers:{Authorization:'Bearer ' + token}
                })
               .map(r=>{type:PROCESSFIRST, data:r.response, item:action.item}),
               Observable.ajax({
                 url:'/second',
                 headers:{Authorization:'Bearer ' + token}
                })
               .map(r=>{type:PROCESSSECOND, data:r.response}),

            )
        })
}
```

The reason I am doing it this way (in case it doesn't make sense) is that I already have an app using redux-thunk (and axios) and I am trying to replace one part of it with redux-observable to get the hang of it, so that is why I want to issue the 2 actions (PROCESSFIRST and PROCESSSECOND) for redux-thunk to deal with as they are already catered for. So I am simply putting a step in the middle to see if I can work with redux-observable but I am very much a newbie to rxjs etc

Ultimately I want to trigger the continuation actions using the data returned and then finish at that.
Also, if you have time, how and where should errors be handled in this.

**UPDATE:**
OK, so I just realised I need a return statement at the top of the epic. That gets me out of the first error.
Then I was using mapTo instead of map, and I was using r.data where it should have r.response. Amazingly it all works now. BUT I am not handling errors correctly OR not calling it in the right way.
So, because of what I said about the existing project using redux-thunk, I have an actionCreator that controls this:

```
initState = (lang) => {
   return dispatch => new Promise(resolve,reject){
     const pr1 = dispatch({type:INIT_STATE});
     //this was another thunk that returned a Promise which did the axios
     //calls to the server, dispatched the relevant continuation action 
     //and then either resolved or rejected
     //and then dispatched further actions to process the results
     const pr2 = dispatch(processData()); 
     Promise.all([pr1,pr2])
       .then(r=>resolve(true))
       .catch(e=>reject(e))
   }
}
```

I have changed this where const pr2 = .... to:

```
const pr2 = dispatch({type:PROCESSDATA})
```

, thereby swapping the thunk for an epic and left everything else the same. This does seem to trigger the epic and process the data but for example if I use the wrong url, nothing happens (as expected) but more importantly I don't catch the error. So what do I need to change to catch that error?
thanks in advance

Comment: and clearly I am a bit of a newbie to Promises - as the then occurs before the ajax...map.So it is not getting a promise back which is why it doesn't catch the error.
So how should this be done? Can I promisify the epic somehow? Or do I need to get rid of the Promise.all in initState? But how would I trigger INIT_STATE and the PROCESSDATA together asynchronously?
Getting confused trying to familiarize with Promises and Rxjs at the same time!

Comment: I tried adding .toPromise() to the .merge but that didn't work. The error occurred after the Promise.all...then executed